# Script to generate a copy of android project with another package name

Tags: android, ant, package

i'm looking to write (or find :D) a script to convert an exisisting Android Project Source to a copy with another package name, that i provide.

Source have package like it.pinco.pallino.source and Copy will be like it.pinco.pallino.test1 etc etc...where test1 is a parameter.

I'm looking to use ANT or this script https://github.com/lijunjieone/RenameAndroidPackage, but there's no README and i don't know python..

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have written to change the package name without having to duplicate any code (for maintainability reasons, I use the same code for the free and pro version of my app).

Here's the script that converts Free version to Pro. It should be pretty easy to adapt it to your needs (provided you work under Linux, or use Cygwin or a linux virtual machine)

```
# 1- rename src folder 
mv src/com/lulo/scrabble/dico src/com/lulo/scrabble/dicopro

# 2- replace references to package in Java, XML and CFG (proguard) files 
find . \( -name "*xml" -o -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cfg" \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri 's/scrabble.dico/scrabble.dicopro/g'

# 3- change the application name
find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri 's/\(Free\)/Pro/g'        

# 4- change the icon
cp ../IMAGES/LOGODICO_V2_2012_96px.png res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
cp ../IMAGES/LOGODICO_V2_2012_72px.png res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
cp ../IMAGES/LOGODICO_V2_2012_48px.png res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
cp ../IMAGES/LOGODICO_V2_2012_36px.png res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
```

After this I just need to Refresh, Build and Export using Eclipse.

Comment: ok, thanks, the problem seems to be solved easily, now i'm going to test this idea to my code! thanks!

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you very much!!! Now I can customize my app for different builds just using shell script.